# How to remove FTP details

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed Wordpres on Linux mashine ( LAMP )

In administration menu, when I delete a plugin it asks for FTP details ( as in attached image ).

Why and how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you wp-config.php and you wont need to add FTP login at all:

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants

Comment: ya, i add this function in wp-config.php and my wordpress website work as add and delete plugin, also i not want need to add ftp login details

Answer (score 0):

Can put these in wp-config.php

```
  define('FTP_USER', 'username');
  define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
  define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21');
 //*If you can use a SSL connection set this to true*
 define('FTP_SSL', true);
```

Comment: when i install new wordpress project also add and remove plugin that time show details in localhost in linux also i add,remove plugin manually folder......